# Is there a way to get ALL values in array or match ALL array contents in PostresSQL query?

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql, typeorm

I was trying to use the BaseEntity.find() or BaseEntity.createQueryBuilder() to get the projects that have certain tags and the tags are in an array. It doesn't seem to work the way we need it to.

Code :

```
const tagArray = ["beta", "innersource"];
.
.
.
const queryBuilder = Project.createQueryBuilder('project').select();
    const projects = await queryBuilder
        .where('project.tags IN (:...tags)', { tags: tagArray })
        .getMany();
    logger.info(projects);
    res.send(projects);
```

So, if I run this code, I only get projects that have only [innersource]  as a tag.
What I want is projects that have both tags ['beta', 'innersource']

Comment: You can try logging the query which gets executed underneath. https://typeorm.io/#/logging/enabling-logging

Comment: You can try to [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array into a string, and pass that into the query.

Comment: @AlexBiro.... I think this is actually the solution! Thank you